# Right derivative at a point and limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let's suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function continuously  differentiable on $(a, b)$, and such that  exist $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)=l\in\mathbb{R}$. We can then define $$\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases}l\qquad\qquad x=a\\f(x)\qquad x\in(a,b)\end{cases},$$ and it is clear that $\tilde{f}\in C^0([a,b))$.

Suppose also that the derivative of $\tilde{f}$ on $x=a$ exist, ie $${\tilde{f}}^{'}(a):=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-l}{h}$$is finite. My question is the following:

> Can I always conclude that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ exist and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)={\tilde{f}}^{'}(a)?$

I know that since $\tilde{f}$ is continuous at $x=a$, then if   $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ is finite the above equality is always true. So the question probably is: is it possible, under the above hypothesis, that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ does't exist (or is infinite)?

Any hint would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO. Let $a=0,b=1$ and $f(x)=x^{2} \sin (\frac 1 x)$. Then $f'(0+)=0$ but $\lim_{x \to 0+}f'(x)$ does not exist.